# Should a helper class implement an interface

Tags: java, oop, interface, helper, design-principles

I am implementing some functionality where I need to create a helper class for custom Math operations. Is it a good practice to implement an interface in this scenario?

Usually we have single implementation for helper classes however in some scenarios we may have complex logic in helper class which can have multiple implementations.

I tried to search on web but could not find answer which is specific to a helper class.

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no specific distinction between helper classes and non-helper classes: if it makes sense that an instance of the helper *is-a* "interface thing", sure, why shouldn't it implement the interface?